# Migration error

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I am getting below error in Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. What is the solution ?

```
[2018-11-13 08:39:48][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 121,163,164 from `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`

[2018-11-13 08:40:17][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields: base_customer_balance_amount,customer_balance_amount,gift_cards_amount,base_gift_cards_amount,gift_cards,used_gift_cards,giftregistry_item_id,gw_id,gw_allow_gift_receipt,gw_add_card,gw_base_price,gw_price,gw_items_base_price,gw_items_price,gw_card_base_price,gw_card_price,gw_base_tax_amount,gw_tax_amount,gw_items_base_tax_amount,gw_items_tax_amount,gw_card_base_tax_amount,gw_card_tax_amount,reward_points_balance,base_reward_currency_amount,reward_currency_amount
```

Comment: from which magento-1 version to which magento-2 version you are trying to migrate?

Comment: From Magento 1.9.8.3. to Magento 2.2.6. Thanks @DhirenVasoya.